# Node.js svd-xbee error: FRAME TYPE NOT IMPLEMENTED: ZigBee Explicit Rx Indicator

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, xbee, svd-xbee

I am using `svd-xbee`0.3.5 with XBee Series 2 running the Coordinator API function set. When running the [package's example](https://github.com/jouz/svd-xbee/blob/master/examples/full/full.js), the console is giving errors

```
FRAME TYPE NOT IMPLEMENTED: ZigBee Explicit Rx Indicator (AO=1) (0x91)
```

The Explicit Rx Indicator should be one of the more common frames, is it really not supported, or is there some misconfiguration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting `AO=0`, which would result in data coming in as `0x90` frames, but you really want to be using Explicit Rx since it will include the source/destination endpoint and cluster information.